# Geometry Nodes. UV Unwrap each mesh island individually

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is an object i'm working with

[image]

I want to split it based on edge angle and then unwrap each mesh island individually from 0;0 to 1;1.
But what happens is it still unwrapps the object as a whole even after splitting geometry
rather than unwrapping each island individually. [image]

Is there a way to do what I want?